# what is the best way to have a physics thread to handle calculations in javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, simulation

I'm making a small 3D physics simulation program in javafx and I looked onto various ways of doing the physics calculations in a separate thread but with little experience in multi threading I find it hard to find the best approach to calculate the physics and passing them to the javafx application

so my question is

What is the best way to do background calculations in javafx?

how to synchronise and pass data between physics thread and javafx application?

Comment: Your question is much to broad. What kind of answers are you hoping for here?

Comment: I used techniques like Timeline with Keyfrrames and I also tried Animationtimer  to use as a main loop.  the basic question is is there something better to use instead of this for 3d gravitation simulation also whats the best way to calculate the physics and pass them to the main loop

Comment: Too broad (and incomplete) a question to really be on-topic for this forum. I recommend looking at the two-part blog though ([part 1](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html), [part 2](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html).

Answer (score 1):

Read the JavaFX concurrency documentation: [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm), [javafx.concurrent.Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).  I won't re-explain it here, as all the base information you need is in the official documentation IMO.  For additional information you can just google for JavaFX threading and concurrency, which will turn up numerous stackoverflow questions that provide further information on this topic.

Consider if you really need your own thread.  Likely, [the physics calculations can be performed quickly on the JavaFX application thread](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) and your own thread is not required.

> its a 3d gravitational simulation of multiple objects >1000 so my performance really drops when I do the physics calculations.

You could use a Task with a [fork/join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) to do calculations in parallel.  Once all calculations are done, you can make a Platform.runLater call to update the UI based upon the updated calculations.

Note that properly implementing fork/join might be kind of complicated for you.  You might want to try just running the calculations in their own task and invoking Platform.runLater when they are done before you attempt the additional complexity of adding something like fork/join.

> what would be the best way to implement my main loop with as I mentioned above I tried Timeline and AnimationTimer, I read AnimationTimer should be better but is there any other alternative?

As you state that performance when everything is done on the JavaFX thread drops too much, then neither a Timeline nor an AnimationTimer will help you all that much as they perform their work on the JavaFX application thread. If you wish, you can try the Task with Platform.runLater call approach as outlined above instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the beginning but its a 3d gravitational simulation of multiple objects >1000 so my performance really drops when I do the physics calculations. Il take a look at the concurrency links u posted, I looked at tasks before but I didnt know if there were any better alternatives.

also what would be the best way to implement my main loop with as I mentioned above I tried Timeline and AnimationTimer, I read AnimationTimer should be better but is there any other alternative? Thanks

Comment: It is best to include that kind of information in the question when you create the question, it might help from creating questions that people just close as too broad.